# In a Dockerfile, gcc is unable find a cloned directory

Tags: git, dockerfile

I have a simple Dockerfile that does a `git clone` and then a `cc` inside the recently cloned directory.  Unfortunately, `cc` fails with an error that the .c file cannot be found.

```
FROM gcc:4.9.4

CMD mdkir -p /usr/src \
    cd /usr/src \
    git clone https://github.com/<repo>/helloworld.git
WORKDIR /usr/src/helloworld
RUN cc -o helloworld -03 -march=native -lm helloworld.c
ENTRYPOINT["./helloworld"]
```

The error seems to indicate that either the clone didn't happen or I'm in the wrong directory when I run `cc`.

```
$ docker build -t helloworld ./
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1/5 : FROM gcc:4.9.4
 ---> 1b3de68a7ff8
Step 2/5 : CMD mkdir -p /usr/src     cd /usr/src     git clone https://github.com/<repo>/helloworld.git /usr/src/helloworld
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b46c44b63d60
Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /usr/src/helloworld
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 11f02812a9e6
Step 4/5 : RUN cc -o helloworld -O3 -march=native -lm helloworld.c
 ---> Running in 784960f375d7

cc: error: helloworld.c: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c cc -o helloworld -O3 -march=native -lm helloworld.c' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Running the each step inside a `docker run --rm -it gcc:4.9.4 /bin/bash` works fine. What assumption am I making that is wrong?

Comment: try `mdkir -p /usr/src && cd /usr/src && git clone https://github.com/<repo>/helloworld.git`

Comment: I had tried that previously and had gotten the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using git, use RUN not CMD.   Hence, a cleaner and easier way to write the Dockerfile is to do the following:

```
FROM gcc:4.9.4

RUN git clone https://github.com/<repo>/helloworld.git /usr/src/helloworld
WORKDIR /usr/src/helloworld
RUN cc -o helloworld -03 -march=native -lm helloworld.c
ENTRYPOINT["./helloworld"]
```